# Z-INDEX Problem in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

If you click the orange ORDER button at the top the **#dimmer** should cover the whole background and the form  should appear at the top. (lightbox-like effect)

The problem is that in IE7 the **#dimmer** would appear at the top regardless of it's **z-index**.

In other browsers everything works nicely.

Link: http://fenelon.ru/projects/SpaceFood/2.1-jQuery/

Thank you, fellows!

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` to element under question.

Comment: `If you click...` click what exactly? What are you asking us? We can't assume that we know what you're asking.....

Comment: Cross-browser is always a pain... Why don't you set the display to none instead of hiding using z-index?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: the *orange* button at the top > how many orange buttons do you see?

Comment: Are we talking stack overflow Orange button? I don't see any orange "ORDER" button here.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: nope, Fenelon gave a link http://fenelon.ru/projects/SpaceFood/2.1-jQuery/

Comment: Sorry, because I still don't see the orange button. Perhaps I don't understand Russian.

Comment: Ok, maybe you would call that marroon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#orderBtn").click(function(){
    if(!visible) {

        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<8) {
            $(".product").css('z-index','-2');
            $("#order").css('z-index','1');
            $("#dimmer").css('z-index','-1');
        }

        ... // do your other stuff

 } else {

        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<8) {
            $(".product,#order,#dimmer").css('z-index','auto');
        }    

        ... // do your other stuff

 }
});
```

Lazy IE7 needs a z-index to all involved elements. This should work now, let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. I want to apologize if my question is somehow unclear, but I've really lost my temper.

Comment: Here's what you've suggested: http://fenelon.ru/projects/SpaceFood/2.1-jQuery/index1.html

Comment: down link? i will try again later…